# How to Add a Button/Hyperlink in every row in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having a dynamic data which is stored in a table in HTML. Now I need a hyperlink or button in every row of the table. So that I should perform some operations.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $index_pointer; $i++)
{
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>". $brands[$i]. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $models[$i]. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $years[$i]. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $categories[$i]. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $frames_size[$i]. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $frames_type[$i]. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $wheels_size[$i]. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $colors[$i]. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $genders[$i]. "</td>";
echo "<td>". $origins[$i]. "</td>"; 
echo "<td>"."<a href=""/>"."</td>";
echo '</tr>';
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Man you should really learn the basics first...

Comment: @AndreiP.tq I'm in beginner stage only can you plz help me to solve this?

Comment: Isn't this working for you? This should do it right? I dont see the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll delete this answer immediatly if this is not what you want or if this isn't the issue but is this what you want?:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $index_pointer; $i++)
{
   echo '<tr>';
   echo "<td>". $brands[$i]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $models[$i]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $years[$i]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $categories[$i]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $frames_size[$i]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $frames_type[$i]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $wheels_size[$i]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $colors[$i]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $genders[$i]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $origins[$i]. "</td>"; 
   echo "<td><a href='URL'>The text that's clickable</a></td>";
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: its working I know its basic but my problem is not only that,now when I click on the hyper link it should take that row values and compare in another table and should show the result.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this.
>
> > mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "ameex") or die(mysql_error());
> >     mysql_select_db("admin") or die(mysql_error());
> >
> > $result =
> >     mysql_query("SELECT * FROM details")  or die(mysql_error());
> >
> > echo "";
> >             echo " TitleImageDescription";         $dir="images/";
> >
> > while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
> >             echo ""; 
> >             echo $row['title'];
> >             echo "";
> >
> > ```
> >     echo "<img src='$dir/$row[image]' width=100px height=100px><br>";
> >     echo"</td><td>";
> >     echo $row['description'];
> >     echo '<td><a href="edit.php?action=edit&title='.$row['title'].'">Edit</a></td> 
> >       <td><a href="delete.php?action=delete&title='.$row['title'].'">Delete</a></td>';
> > echo "</td></tr>";  }
> > ```